# Sitemap with dynamic urls in Django - Case where model pertains to multiple dynamic urls

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm trying to build a sitemap that includes my dynamic urls. I have a Location model that I use to generate dynamic urls for a specific restaurant (at a given location) AND for all restaurants given a location.

The two urls are `/restaurants/<restaurant-name-slug>/<location-name-slug>` and `/restaurants/<ocation-name-slug>` , respectively

How do I generate the dynamic urls for both of these urls so that they appear on my sitemap file? It seems like each model can only take one url in the `get_absolute_url` method inside models.py

Here is what I have in my `models.py`, which works fine for the `/restaurants/<ocation-name-slug>` url but not the other url:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    name_slug = ...
    city = ...
    longitude = ...
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_restaurant', args=[self.name_slug])

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the setup here. It seems to me that in the first URL, with both the restaurant and location, the location doesn't provide any information that isn't already there. Why not have the Location model return the `/restaurants/<location-name-slug>` URL and the Restaurant model return `/restaurants/<restaurant-name-slug>`? I don't see what location adds here.

Comment: you are correct. I just made some models on the spot, but I have a use case where the location model is used to generate dynamic urls across multiple pages. So for the purposes of this example, let's just imagine that this case is valid

Comment: Then it seems to me like what you're doing doesn't really fit the purpose of `get_absolute_url`. As far as I understand it, you use `get_absolute_url` to return the one, single, absolute URL to the resource--as the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) say, the "canonical URL" of the object. Since there are multiple URLs that a single model object is related to, then there is, by definition, no absolute URL. You could just define a `get_all_urls` function yourself or something like that. Why do you need `get_absolute_urls`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I guess I'm not familiar with sitemaps in Django. I just figured `get_absolute_url` was the way of doing this. What is `get_all_urls`? That might be what I am looking for. I have a feeling I'm going about this wrong, so I appreciate the input

Comment: What I'm saying is just write your own function that does exactly what you want (get_all_urls is just an example name). No reason to use get_absolute_urls here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for "dynamic urls" here, let alone multiple ones. And there is no need to tie anything to `get_absolute_url`.

Rather, you have two completely standard patterns in your urls.py: one for restaurant and one for restaurant-location.

```
urls = [
   url(r'^locations/(?P<location_slug>\w+)/$', views.location, name='location'), 
   url(r'^restaurants/(?P<restaurant_slug>\w+)/$', views.restaurant, name='restaurant'),
]
```